# PHP: Which is more efficient: a concatonated return variable, or returning each line individually?

Tags: php, html, performance

I have a sytem where I want to build an HTML table in PHP from data retrieved from a databse.

I've previously used two different methods for creating the HTML and echoing it.

Building a return variable, and echoing at the end of the PHP script:

```
<?php
$data['category']['parts']; // format of the data

$retval = '<table>';
foreach($data as $category) {
  $retval .= '<tr>';
  foreach($category as $data) {
    $retval .= '<td>'.$data.'</td>'
  }
  $retval .= '</tr>';
}
$retval .= '</table>';

echo $retval;
```

The other method is to echo each line as the code comes to it:

```
<?php
$data['category']['parts']; // format of the data

echo '<table>';
foreach($data as $category) {
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach($category as $data) {
    echo '<td>'.$data.'</td>'
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Which of the two methods is more efficient, in terms of processor/memory usage, and also for processing speed?
Is there actually a real difference, rather than just a question of style?

Comment: i would go with echo $retval; because its more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My shot is: whatever you find more readable. Impact on performance is so small that probably you won't see any difference.

However, if you really care, `echo` should be faster (nothing better than a performance test on your specific scenario) because string concatenation will resize `retval` multiple times (and this will impact performance).

Even better you should avoid concatenation also in your `echo`:

```
<?php
$data['category']['parts']; // format of the data

echo '<table>';
foreach($data as $category) {
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach($category as $data) {
    echo '<td>', $data, '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Do you want to do better? Just construct your own string builder object (but, honestly, gain is so small that you should seriously consider if worth your effort).

Comment: but still you are calling language construct which also do some stuff to return html ?  :/

Comment: @NullPoiиteя absolutely but `echo` is somehow faster than (let's say) `printf` and for a literal string like this it won't (should?!) perform any new string allocation (string copy by value is optimized and with increasing size of `retval` you won't copy huge strings). I'd agree it's such small difference you won't ever care about (unless you're working on Facebook). Yes, no inline string stuff but allocation & copy are heavier. BTW string concatenation `.` improved a lot in PHP5.

Comment: exactly for almost 99% cases no need to care about this http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y43kKM  http://codepad.viper-7.com/xILtNl s

Comment: Agree, I would highlight that more on my answer. I think even something more readable is better (shorttags, as suggested by dognose, I don't know about their performance).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'd not considered the processing time of the string concatenation adjusting the length.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use kind of a templating to generate your page, I would rewrite your code to something like this.

(this can be in a dedicated file, and just `included` to display output)

```
<?php
$data['category']['parts']; // format of the data
?>

include ('templates/theFileIWantToShow.php');

---- snip files here. Processing above, template bellow.

<table>
  <?foreach($data as $category):?>
    <tr>
    <?foreach($category as $data):?>
       <td><?=$data?></td>
    <?endforeach;?>
    </tr>
  <?endforeach;?>
</table>
```

This would offer (imho) best readability when it comes down to large html pages with only a few **wildcards**.

Advantages:

- You get clean html with only a few spots of php in between
- You can easily replace the template files without touching the generating code
- you can reuse templates. Providing direct output and/or building strings is a mess, when it comes down to reuse the *same* html-markup for a certain element over and over.

Note that this requires shorttags to be enabled in your php.ini for PHP < 5.4.0.

Comment: you dont require to enable short since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available

Comment: Thanks for the styling advice, but I was more after efficiency, and the answer above has that covered much better